# Does the corruption ability of Corrupters stack?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-zerg

Does the corruption ability of Corrupters stack?  In other words, if I corrupt a battlecruiser once, it takes an extra 20% damage.  If i corrupt it again,does it then take 20% more damage?  I can't seem to find a reference anywhere for this.  In brood war, it was obvious that devourer's spores did stack, because the unit portrait for the victim unit would tell you how many spores were on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried, and sadly, it does not stack.

Comment: agreed.  I did some testing myself and when a unit is corrupted, it does get a little icon on it's portrait.

Comment: I can't think of any ability effect in Starcraft II that stacks.

Comment: @carl the only thing that comes to mind is the VR charge level.